# Handlebars not rendering?

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, handlebars.js

I've been following this [tutorial](https://medium.com/laravel-4/laravel-4-real-time-chat-eaa550829538) in order to develop a chat system to my Laravel application, but some things seem outdated and I'm really new into Handlebars and JS. On step "**Creating an interface**", I've tried to adapt the code provided in the tutorial to the syntax required in Handlebars 3.0 but everything I get is a blank page. Looks like the Handlebars views are not rendering at all and I'm probably stuck in some very basic issue. Here are my codes.

### chat.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt">
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <link
            rel="stylesheet"
            type="text/css"
            href="{{ asset("css/bootstrap.css") }}"
        />
        <link
            rel="stylesheet"
            type="text/css"
            href="{{ asset("css/bootstrap.theme.css") }}"
        />
        <title>Laravel 4 Chat</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/x-handlebars-template">
            @{{outlet}}
        </script>
        <script
            type="text/x-handlebars-template"
            data-template-name="chat"
            id='chat'
        >
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <h1>Laravel 4 Chat</h1>
                        <table class="table table-striped">
                            @{{#each}}
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        @{{user}}
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        @{{text}}
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            @{{/each}}
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input
                                type="text"
                                class="form-control"
                            />
                            <span class="input-group-btn">
                                <button class="btn btn-default">
                                    Send
                                </button>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </script>
        <script
            type="text/javascript"
            src="{{ asset("js/shared.js") }}"
        ></script>
        <script
            type="text/javascript"
            src="{{ asset("js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js") }}"
        ></script>
        <script
            type="text/javascript"
            src="{{ asset("js/handlebars-v3.0.0.js") }}"
        ></script>
        <script
            type="text/javascript"
            src="{{ asset("js/handlebars.runtime-v3.0.0.js") }}"
        ></script>
        <script
            type="text/javascript"
            src="{{ asset("js/ember.debug.js") }}"
        ></script>
        <script
            type="text/javascript"
            src="{{ asset("js/ember-data.js") }}"
        ></script>
        <script
            type="text/javascript"
            src="{{ asset("js/bootstrap.js") }}"
        ></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready( function() {
                var source   = $("#chat").html();
                var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

### shared.js:

```
// 1
var App = Ember.Application.create();
// 2
App.Router.map(function() {
    this.resource("chat", {
        "path" : "/chat/"
    });
});
// 3
App.Message = DS.Model.extend({
    "user" : DS.attr("string"),
    "text" : DS.attr("string")
});
// 4
App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.FixtureAdapter.extend();
// 5
App.Message.FIXTURES = [
    {
        "id"   : 1,
        "user" : "Chris",
        "text" : "Hello World."
    },
    {
        "id"   : 2,
        "user" : "Wayne",
        "text" : "Don't dig it, man."
    },
    {
        "id"   : 3,
        "user" : "Chris",
        "text" : "Meh."
    }
];
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think ember is not supporting handlebars (hdbs) 3.0 at the moment.

Please have a look at this [post for a handlebars update info](http://emberjs.com/blog/2014/10/16/handlebars-update.html). Not sure if this is up-to-date, but it seems that only hdbs 1.x is supported.

Because Ember has changed to HTMLBars, see this [post](http://emberjs.com/blog/2015/02/05/compiling-templates-in-1-10-0.html) for infos to the change. They probably won't add support for hdbs 3.0.

There is also a [jsbin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/) where you can see how to use the latest version of emberJS.